# how to set up ec2 (database server) connection to a android app(android studio for development)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-ec2, connection

I'm planning to create an android app which utilizes aws-ec2 as its database server, but I don't know how to connect those two together. What will be the first step for me to do?

Comment: Provide the database connection string in your app config.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Amazon EC2, you should try **Amazon RDS** which is used for creating database server(MySQL, ...). It will provide you with the information like:

- Database name
- Username & Password
- Database Host
- ...etc

So you can use those information to associate with your Android app.